# Integral involving exponential of sine and cosine

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I would like to compute the following integral

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi~e^{-a|\cos(\phi)|-b|\sin(\phi)|}$.

It resembles to some extent the integral representation of the Bessel functions of the first kind but the second term in the argument of the exponential function seems to be a major obstacle. I would be happy about any suggestions! Thanks.

Comment: does harmonic addition theorem helps?

Comment: Also, try partitioning the integral into 4 parts, each of interval of length half-pi.